# How to unload a function from another namespace?

Tags: clojure

I load a function `say-hi` from namespace learning.greeting

```
(use 'learning.greeting)
```

When I try to re-defn the say-hi function under the current (user) namespace, I got the error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalStateException: say-hi already refers to: #'learning.greeting/say-hi in namespace: user, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
```

So how to unload the function from other namespaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get rid of a direct mapping to a Var from another namespace at the REPL, say

```
(ns-unmap 'current-namespace 'local-alias)
```

Example:

```
user=> (ns-unmap *ns* 'reduce)
nil
user=> (reduce + 0 [1 2 3])
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: reduce in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:2:1)
```

Local alias will differ from the actual name of the Var if `:rename` was used:

```
(use '[clojure.walk
       :only [keywordize-keys]
       :rename {keywordize-keys keywordize}])
```

To remove all mappings pointing at Vars in `clojure.walk`:

```
(doseq [[sym v] (ns-map *ns*)]
  (if (and (var? v)
           (= (.. v -ns -name) 'clojure.walk))
    (ns-unmap *ns* sym)))
```

Comment: Thank you. `ns-unmap` handle this very well.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to remove `say-hi` from `learning.greeting`?  If not, it might be better to use `require` in this situation.  Instead of `(use 'learning.greeting)`, execute:

```
(require `[learning.greeting :as lg])
```

Then you can refer to the original definition as `lg/say-hi`, and you can define a new version in the current namespace, e.g. as

```
 (def say-hi [x] (lg/say-hi (list x x))
```

(I don't know whether that makes sense for the `say-hi` function, but the general point is the same regardless.)

Comment: Yes, it is "better to use require in this situation". I'll follow this advice from now on. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

both `use` and `require` have an :exclude parameter for just this situation:

```
(use '[learning.greeting :exclude [say-hi]])
```

or more preferably use require:

```
(require '[learning.greeting :refer :all :exclude [say-hi]])
```

or when you are working in a normal namespace putting all this in the `ns` form is preferred:

```
(ns my-namespace
   (:require [learning.greeting :refer [ function1 function2] :as greeting]
```